# Kotlin library was complied with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I tried to run Kotlin file on Android Studio (version 4.1) and I got an error:
Kotlin library {0} was compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin plugin.

Even I got this error I'm able to run kotlin files but Ide don't gives me tips when I use kotlin functions and methods are marked by red colour. Kotlin version in gradle is 1.6.0, if I'm return to older version I can see tips about method names and red colour is not showed.
Gradle build(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kotlin_udemy4"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Gradle build:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Does anyon know how to resolve that issue ?

Comment: The latest officially released version is 1.6.21. You can change it at the top of the project level build.gradle file.

Comment: Thank you for advice but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem. To solve this, I do the following things:

1. I try to Rebuild the project, then this error log appear:
   The minCompileSdk (32) specified in a
   dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
   is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
   Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.5.0.
   AAR metadata file: C:\Users..........
2. Lower androidx.appcompat:appcompat version to 1.4.0, and then sync gradle. That's it.

Maybe you can try this way.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Kotlin version `1.6.21` ...

That version of Android Studio appears rather outdated; eg. the current version "Chipmunk" uses:

- `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1`
- `jcenter()` should be replaced with `mavenCentral()`.
- And also, use `JavaVersion.VERSION_11`.

Comment: Do we need `JavaVersion.VERSION_11` in our build?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the **gradle** version of your project.

You can try the following steps to resolve this error, by upgrading the version of your android studio in the following steps.

1. Go to the **buil.gradle** (Project level) and update the version of your build tools and plugin

   dependencies {
   //Old version
   classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-rc01"
   classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"

   ```
      // change to the new one
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2"
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
   ```

   }
2. Now navigate to the **gradle-wrapper.properties** and update your gradel version

// old version
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip

// change to the new version
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip

3. And finally change your compile sdk version in **build.gradle**(module level)

//old version
compileSdk 31

//new version
compileSdk 34

Please sometime If you are not sure with the new version simply scroll the mouse on the previous version and the new version will be highlighted which you can update accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Next to isssue popup i selected "Details" link and there was information about expected version. Probably because I'm using older Android studio I got the problem. I updated Kotlin in gradle build to: 1.4.32 according to message.
[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer, next time please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72468897/edit) button.

Comment: Why? It resolved my problem.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: I’m also confused as to why this isn’t an answer.

Comment: This `build.gradle` has multiple issues and `1.4.32` is way older than the `1.6.0` in the question. There's defintely no way the `jcenter()` repository would provide any dependencies - only `google()` is used. `targetSdk 31` and Java 8 also is questionable.

Comment: The point is, that Kotlin has changed ...so you might learnt it in a way which doesn't matter anymore; the `buildToolsVersion` also doesn't match the `targetSdk`. One certainly can build with old versions, but they should at least match - but not against current Android API, which require current tooling. Random versions = random problems. The Gradle version is also an important aspect.

Comment: What do you mean by "Kotlin has changed", It's not like java so If someon write in java 8 for most of his life, switching to java 13 wouldn't be a big difference right ? 
I mainain old app, mostly wirtten in java but because of android 12 some features is easier to write in kotlin. This is why I'm using old version of kotlin and android studio.